# Plotly continuous_colour_scale not accepting numpy array

Tags: python, string, numpy, plotly, graphing

Have used the following syntax to feed Plotly correct axis order that I would like.

```
Gval = ['G_kcsa_000_0','G_kcsa_000_10','G_kcsa_000_19','G_kcsa_500_0','G_kcsa_500_10','G_kcsa_500_19','G_drude_000_0','G_drude_000_10','G_drude_000_19','G_MthK_000_0','G_MthK_000_10','G_MthK_000_19']

clusters_df = pd.read_csv('K-W_unique.csv')
clusters_df2 = pd.read_csv('K-flip_unique.csv')

Y1_order_df = pd.read_csv('Y1_order.csv')
Y2_order_df = pd.read_csv('Y2_order.csv')
X_order_df = pd.read_csv('X_order.csv')

def     df_to_plotly(clusters_df,G,flip):
        return {'z': clusters_df[G].tolist(),
                'x': clusters_df.KPattern2.tolist(),
                'y': clusters_df[flip].tolist()}

X_order = X_order_df.to_numpy()
Y1_order = Y1_order_df.to_numpy()
Y2_order = Y2_order_df.to_numpy()

print(X_order)
print(Y1_order)
print(Y2_order)


def     waterFlip(plot_title,img_title,cluster,flip,order):


                for i in Gval:

                        fig = go.Figure()

                        fig.add_trace(go.Heatmap(df_to_plotly(cluster,i,flip),
                                colorscale='Jet', zmax=8.0, zmin=0, colorbar=dict(
                                        title='G (kT)'
                                        )
                                )
                        )

                        fig.update_layout(
                                width = 1000, height = 1000,
                                paper_bgcolor='white',
                                plot_bgcolor='sky blue')

                        fig.update_yaxes(tickmode='linear',tickangle=45,categoryorder='array', categoryarray=order, title=plot_title)
                        fig.update_xaxes(tickmode='linear',tickangle=45,categoryorder='array', categoryarray=X_order, title='POT')

                        fig.show()
                        fig.write_image(i+img_title+".png")

waterFlip('WATER','-K-W', clusters_df,'WPattern2','Y1_order')
waterFlip('Flipping Pattern G-Y-G-V-T','-K-flip', clusters_df2,'G_Y_G_V_T','Y2_order')
```

This is the output printed to screen:

```
[['S4']
 ['S5']
 ['S1_B34']
 ['S1_S4']
 ['B12_B34']
 ['B12_S4']
 ['B12_S5']
 ['S2_S4']
 ['S2_B34']
 ['B23_S4']
 ['S3_S5']
 ['S0_S1_B34']
 ['S0_S2_B34']
 ['S0_S2_S4']
 ['S1_S2_S4']
 ['S1_S3_S4']
 ['S1_S3_S5']
 ['B12_S3_S4']
 ['B12_S3_S5']
 ['B12_B34_S5']
 ['S1_B23_S5']
 ['S1_B34_S5']
 ['S2_B34_S5']
 ['OV_S1_S3_S5']
 ['OV_S2_S3_S5']
 ['S0_B12_B34_S5']
 ['S0_B12_S3_S5']
 ['S0_S2_B34_S5']
 ['S0_S2_S3_S5']
 ['poorly defined']]
[['OV']
 ['OV_S1']
 ['OV_S2']
 ['OV_B23']
 ['OV_S3']
 ['OV_S0_S1']
 ['OV_S0_S2']
 ['OV_S0_S3']
 ['OV_S1_S2']
 ['OV_S1_S3']
 ['OV_S1_B23']
 ['OV_S2_S4']
 ['OV_B23_S4']
 ['OV_S3_S4']
 ['OV_S0_S1_S2']
 ['OV_S0_S1_B23']
 ['OV_S0_S1_S3']
 ['OV_S0_S2_S4']
 ['OV_S0_B23_S4']
 ['OV_S0_B23_S5']
 ['OV_S0_S3_B34']
 ['OV_S0_S3_S4']
 ['OV_S1_S2_S3']
 ['OV_S1_S2_B34']
 ['OV_S1_B23_S4']
 ['OV_S1_B23_S5']
 ['OV_S1_S3_S4']
 ['OV_B12_S3_S4']
 ['OV_S2_S3_S4']
 ['OV_B23_S3_S4']
 ['OV_S0_S1_B23_S4']
 ['OV_S0_S1_B34_S5']
 ['OV_S0_S2_B23_S4']
 ['OV_S1_B23_S4_S5']
 ['OV_S1_B12_B23_S4']
 ['OV_S0_S1_B12_S2_B23_S3_B34_S4']
 ['poorly defined']]
[['0F_0F_0F_0F_0F']
 ['0F_1F_0F_0F_0F']
 ['0F_0F_1F_0F_0F']
 ['0F_0F_2Fo_0F_0F']
 ['0F_0F_0F_1F_0F']
 ['0F_0F_0F_2Fo_0F']
 ['0F_0F_0F_2Fs_0F']
 ['0F_0F_0F_3F_0F']
 ['0F_0F_0F_4F_0F']
 ['0F_2Fo_0F_0F_0F']
 ['0F_1F_1F_0F_0F']
 ['0F_1F_2Fo_0F_0F']
 ['0F_2Fo_1F_0F_0F']
 ['0F_2Fs_2Fo_0F_0F']
 ['0F_3F_1F_0F_0F']
 ['0F_1F_0F_2Fo_0F']
 ['0F_0F_1F_3F_0F']
 ['0F_1F_1F_1F_0F']
 ['0F_2Fs_0F_1F_0F']
 ['0F_2Fo_0F_2Fo_0F']
 ['0F_2Fs_1F_1F_0F']
 ['0F_2Fo_1F_2Fo_0F']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "heatmap.py", line 57, in <module>
    waterFlip('WATER','-K-W', clusters_df,'WPattern2','Y1_order')
  File "heatmap.py", line 51, in waterFlip
    fig.update_yaxes(tickmode='linear',tickangle=45,categoryorder='array', categoryarray=order, title=plot_title)
  File "/Users/billy/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/plotly/graph_objs/_figure.py", line 21858, in update_yaxes
    obj.update(patch, overwrite=overwrite, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/billy/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py", line 5122, in update
    BaseFigure._perform_update(self, kwargs, overwrite=overwrite)
  File "/Users/billy/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py", line 3929, in _perform_update
    plotly_obj[key] = val
  File "/Users/billy/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py", line 4859, in __setitem__
    self._set_prop(prop, value)
  File "/Users/billy/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py", line 5203, in _set_prop
    raise err
  File "/Users/billy/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/plotly/basedatatypes.py", line 5198, in _set_prop
    val = validator.validate_coerce(val)
  File "/Users/billy/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/_plotly_utils/basevalidators.py", line 404, in validate_coerce
    self.raise_invalid_val(v)
  File "/Users/billy/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site-packages/_plotly_utils/basevalidators.py", line 288, in raise_invalid_val
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: 
    Invalid value of type 'builtins.str' received for the 'categoryarray' property of layout.yaxis
        Received value: 'Y1_order'

    The 'categoryarray' property is an array that may be specified as a tuple,
    list, numpy array, or pandas Series
```

I am confused because Y1_order is clearly defined as a numpy array.

How do I fix this?

Would like the X and Y axes reordered in images like the following:

[image]

[image]

Wanted the axes to have the custom order that I have given it via the numpy array.

Comment: It's pretty difficult to see what's happening here. It would be a lot easier to help if you made your question reproducible. Since you used Pandas, you could edit your question and paste the results of `pd.DataFrame.to_dict` for each of your data frames.